Store data in marker and then access that data when calling function from marker click - TkinterMapView, Tkinter, Python
I'm using TkinterMapView (https://github.com/TomSchimansky/TkinterMapView), and I'm trying to store data in a maker when I create it and then access said data when I call a function from it.
My code is as follows:
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkintermapview import TkinterMapView
from tkinter import simpledialog

class App(tkinter.Tk):

    APP_NAME = "name.py"
    WIDTH = 800
    HEIGHT = 750

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

#command that im calling from the marker
        def click_command(self, marker):
            self.map_widget.delete_all_marker()
#creating marker
        self.map_widget.set_marker(56.243350, -3.9111328, text="Example_text", marker_color_circle = '#E622C5', command = self.click_command)

What I've tried -
In the docs it states, "You can also store an object or some reference inside the marker with the data attribute, which can be set when creating a marker, and accessed or modified with marker.data."
So, I've tried adding to the bottom of the above code after self.map_widget.set_marker:
self.map_widget.data('test value')

and
self.map_widget.data(9999)

I did a bit of pressing and guessing and got it working by adding "data: any = None" to the def init, and then just "data=" when making the marker and using .data in the called function. Equating to the following code:
def __init__(self, data: any=None, *args, **kwargs):
    tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def click_command(self, marker):
            string = marker.data
    
    self.map_widget.set_marker(56.243350, -3.9111328, text="Example_text", marker_color_circle = '#E622C5', command = self.click_command, data='some string')



Does this answer your question? How do you programmatically set an attribute?

Hi @Joooeey, Thanks! yes that worked for a single marker (object), the problem was I was creating these markers in a loop (my fault for simplifying the code) so only saved for the last loop. I figured it out and edit my question

It is not clear what your issue is.  It is better to elaborate more in the question.

@JoshAlton if your question is resolved, you should put your answer in the answer box below, not in the question. If it is not resolved, please make clear what is still missing.
